# How to mining on Ubuntu 18.04 with AMD cards

Tags: mining, gpu-mining, ubuntu

The new Ubuntu system is about to be released, how could you set it to mining Monero with AMD cards? AMD new drivers on the horizon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest Radeon AMD driver, and programs like xmr-stak or cast_xmr, is easy to mine **Monero** with AMD GPU cards under Ubuntu 18.04.

References:

AMD Radeon Linux driver - https://www.amd.com/en/support

XMR-stak - https://github.com/xmr-stak

Cast_XMR - https://github.com/glph3k/cast_xmr